# How to authenticate Role with Entrust for Frozennode Administrator

Tags: laravel

I am using [Confide (v3.2)](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and [Entrust(v1.2)](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) with [Frozennode Administrator](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator). In the config file there is an option which I need to set that will return true/false depending on if the user is authenticated.

```
/**
 * The permission option is the highest-level authentication check that lets you define a closure that should return true if the current user
 * is allowed to view the admin section. Any "falsey" response will send the user back to the 'login_path' defined below.
 *
 * @type closure
 */
'permission'=> function()
{
    return Auth::check();
},
```

It is using the default Laravel Auth:check(); I used confide Confide to authenticate users, but it just verifies any User is authenticated and I need to make sure they have the Admin role to use the Administrator. I am using Entrust for roles and want to get the equivalent. I only see in the documentation for Entrust to use

```
$user->hasRole("Admin");
```

But I know this won't work because $user is not defined. How do I do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with the packages you use, but if you can use ``Auth::check()``, perhaps you could also use ``Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')`` to get the current user's status? Probably not, but I thought I'd throw it out there. :)

Comment: I think you are correct. Seems so obvious, but I guess I wasn't thinking straight! I am having other issues so I cannot verify and will come back to accept you answer if you make one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the packages you use, but if you can use `Auth::check()`, you can probably also use `Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')` to get the current user's status and go from there.